# Можно ли запустить программу на .NET Core так, чтобы можно было пошагово дебажить код .NET Core?

Tags: c#, отладка, .net-core

Это нужно, чтобы видеть, что происходит внутри фреймворка. Возможно такое? Если да, то есть ли инструкции, как всё это дело настроить?

Например, взять тот же WPF (в данном случае это к .NET Core никакого отношения не имеет), начитаешься ты книг, вроде бы более-менее всё понятно, но как оно реально работает остаётся загадкой. Собственно по этой причине я и хочу иметь возможность дебажить .NET Core, чтобы в самые дебри забираться и видеть, как оно работает.

Comment: .NET Core проект опенсорсный, скачайте с гитхаба сорцы, и дебажте как хотите.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)

Comment: С Visual Studio проблем не должно быть. Вот официальная документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source

Comment: С другой стороны, фреймворки типа WPF достаточно сложные, так что вам быстро надоест лезть в дебри :)